# How do I install a Windows update that gives an error but no further information?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I tried to install a Windows update but it keeps failing with this error.

[image]

I click on the link 'Get help with this error' and it opens an empty help page.

[image]

I searched for the error number and found this

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-update/windows-update-encountered-an-error-code-84b30002/190aac5b-6947-4ee4-bece-e302eceb605d?auth=1

I restarted, moved the SoftwareDistribution folder to \TEMP, and re-ran Windows update. It still failed. I don't have confidence anything else suggested on that page will help.

The software update that fails is

[image]

Comment: Little tip, if your asking for help installing an update, helpful to say specifically which update it is.  Shouldn’t make assume it’s the update in the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can try manually downloading the update from Microsoft: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26727) (via [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=kb2528583))

Once you've downloaded and installed that then you should be able to re-run Windows update and it should no longer pester you for this update.  At a minimum it should hopefully give you some more information on what went wrong.

Comment: agreed. SQLServer SPs almost always need a manual download and install.

Comment: I manually installed the update without an error, and selected 'Check for Updates' in Windows Update, but it still lists the same optional update KB2528583 as available. I tried to install it again, and it still gave the error.

Comment: @Chloe  Have you rebooted since installing the update?  It might have pending changes that cannot happen while the system is up. A quick search reveals that at least one person rebooted twice after manually installing and it worked.

Comment: @Mokubai I restarted (several times since) and the update is still there. It didn't work.